# Count the data under such specific ID No. from a table on the Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't know the syntax in PHP but I want to COUNT the "1"s of a certain ID no. then Display the result. In this case the desired result would be 3, 3 and 5. Since all bookstatus value on every book ID is "1". If the value of bookstatus changes from 1 to 2 then it will only COUNT the "1"s. See attached photo. 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you want to create the table in a database by PHP code so no need to worry its automatically counter increment by default.

Comment: You want to create manually in database so you need to put 1 2 3 like that value in your bookId field.

Comment: that table was already created on another form, my problem is how to get the total "1" count of each id number. Im new to PHP programming.

Comment: you mean to say you want id as like 1 in every row.

Comment: I want to count how many "1" on each ID no :) 
1001 = 3 ones
1002 = 3 ones
1003 = 5 ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT bookID, COUNT(*) from your_table GROUP BY bookID WHERE bookStatus = 1
```

the above query returns all availabe books per bookID. you can add bookID in where status for certain bookID

**Edit: Select data from database and fetch it(a sample code based on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm)):**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Selecting Table in MySQLi Server</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'TUTORIALS';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
         $sql = 'SELECT name FROM tutorials_inf';
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT bookID, COUNT(*) from bookstock GROUP BY bookID WHERE bookStatus = 1"
 $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
How to display the result of this query? :)

Comment: THANK YOU @Highlan,. You solved my problem :D

Comment: @zurata your welcome :)

Comment: Hi i dont know how to display the result. im sorry

Comment: @zurata use this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm for tuts about fetch data. (and i will edit my answer too!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `count()` function in php to count the number of bookId available count in your database and fetch to display in your webpage.

`$query = "SELECT bookId, COUNT(bookId) FROM tableName WHERE bookId ='1001' ";`

Now fetch the result to your webpage.

Comment: Im not sure but I want to count the number "1" on a certain ID no. for example, I want to count how many "1" on ID no 1001 the answer is 3. Only the "1" value of a certain ID No.

Comment: your question is not too much understandable. Please explain clearly what do you want to output.

Comment: If you use the `count()` function to the bookId where the id is 1001 it will output the result 3 because there are 3 bookId which has value '1001'.

Comment: i want to count the number "1" under a certain ID no (Ex. 1001) if the value of 1 changes to 2 then it will display 2 because the other 1 was change into 2.